# Show Notification when app is open, not just when it's closed

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I'm working on project using react-native-push-notification my config file is like below:

```
    PushNotification.configure({
          onRegister: function (token) {
          },
    
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log("On Notification",notification)
         },
      onAction: function (notification) {
        console.log("On Notification Action")
      },
      onRegistrationError: function(err) {
        console.error(err.message, err);
      },
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
```

If the app is closed the notification is shown, but if it's opened the notification is not showing, I want to  show the notification even if the app is opened.
how to achieve that is this a parameter to add in the configure ?

Comment: On Android, notifications will only show up as new Icon in the statusbar but not pop up if the app is in foreground